# How to extract data from an api using python and convert it into a pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, api

I want to load the data from an API into a pandas data frame. How may I do that? The following is my code snippet:

```
import requests
import json
response_API = requests.get('https://data.spiceai.io/eth/v0.1/gasfees?period=1d')
#print(response_API.status_code)
data = response_API.text
parse_json = json.loads(data)
```

Comment: You should start by installing/importing pandas and then building your dataframe from the list of dictionaries. You also can use response_API.json() so you don't have to manually convert it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost there, the json is clean you can directly input it to a dataframe :

```
response_API = requests.get('https://data.spiceai.io/eth/v0.1/gasfees?period=1d')
data = response_API.json()
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```